# Is there any Ethiopian calendar readily available for websites?

Tags: php, jquery, html, calendar, fullcalendar

Is there any Ethiopian JQuery/HTML calendars available? I have a requirement where we need to use this calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is an Ethiopian calendar available in Jquery.
Please see the following link and search for Ethiopian
http://keith-wood.name/calendars.html

Comment: I got the code for datepicker.. http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html

Comment: Thanks Sir for your info.. I got the code for datepicker.. http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html. Im looking for a good ethiopian week calendar. Will keep posted.

Comment: Hi,I developed one in PHP but it is not live yet. It will be launched at http://ethiopianlanguages.com/ethiopian-calendar/ within few weeks. I am not sure about the intended purpose, but would it be useful for weekly calendar list without its code? Or is there any other way I can help with this?

Comment: Hello Yibe, We need to create a events calendar like http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html but in Ethiopia..