# Ethiopian Date Picker for Python

Tags: python, qt, datepicker, calendar, pyqt

I'm currently developing a python application using the Qt. The application shall allow to enter/select an ethiopian date, which is different from the date of a gregorian calendar. 
To support date selection, I plan to add a date picker widget that allows to quickly select the desired date from an ehtiopian calendar.

Unfortunately the Qt calendar widget class does not provide the necessary functionality, since it only supports the gregorian calendar.

So, does anybody know about a date picker written in python that supports the ethiopian calendar?

Comment: You would almost certainly have to write this yourself as I'm sure there are many differences between a more wide-spread calendar and an Ethiopian calendar. Perhaps you could salvage the guts of another Qt calendar widget and just change the logic to work with an Ethiopian calendar?

Comment: Interesting problem but likely to get closed because SO doesn't like questions asking for libaries (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176817/is-there-any-ethiopian-calendar-readily-available-for-websites)

Comment: @Oasiscircle: That's what I try to avoid, although I already started doing just that..